# Weird behavior of Visual Studio 2013 RC3 XAML Designer

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml, xamlparseexception, app.xaml

I'm having lots of problems with the Visual Studio designer, for a couple of days in a Windows 8.1 .net 4.5.1 project. I did not change anything in my source code. A heavy XAML loaded page doesn't load but neither for simplest empty page; This is the XAML for the simple page:

```
<Page
x:Class="MyTrip.BlankPage2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyTrip"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</Grid>
```

Since I have been working with visual studio I had similar projects, and I debugged the XDescProc.exe in order to guess what was happening. Nothing worked on this one, this error is shown:

[image]

An exception happened as always with the designer. This exception isn't related to my code, and I will show you why; I'm developing also a Windows Phone 8.1 app, and since I have an Universal Project I made a test. I droped the XAML related to the view (the heavy page) giving me that exception to the Universal Project. I double-clicked and... It works both for the heavy page and the simple page.

So in the Windows 8.1 project breaks, and in the universal project works... Why? Since the universal project is just a reference in Windows 8.1 project, what would make the designer break under the Windows project? Any help on this? I have to make the designer work on WIndows 8.1 project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try clearing the contents of the following folders under your Windows user profile:

AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache
AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Blend\ShadowCache

You do need to have all instances of Visual Studio 2013 and Blend for Visual Studio 2013 closed before deleting the contents of those two folders.